# Can telegram bot create a group after setting a certain command?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

Can the bot create a group chat after setting a certain command?
E.g., a user pushes a button and a new chat is created for him and another user

I know that in the previous Telegram APIs bot cannot do that. Are there any changes?

Answer (score 1):

No thats not possible, the Telegram Bot API does not provide any options to create groups.

Since you're asking for a group with just the bot and the user, you could talk personally to the user from the bot.